# Yii2 + ajax (обновление представления)

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii, pjax

Есть представление корзины с товарами.

При нажатии на удаление товара нужно обновить то же самое представление при помощи ajax(-а).

**Проблема** в том, что в функцию ajax попадает это представление, но не понятно куда его вставлять методом `$('').html();`

```
public function actionDelItemApp($id) {
    return $this->render('view');
}
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/cart/del-item-app',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (data) {
             if (!data) alert('PRODUCT NOT FOUND!');
             $('НЕ ЗНАЮ КУДА ВСТАВЛЯТЬ').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Представление:
`div.section` и т.д.

В аякс попадает все содержимое блока `div.section` ВКЛЮЧАЯ его.

И куда вставлять результат?

Comment: Для конкретики, хорошо бы было привести свой код, в котором вы испытываете затруднение

Comment: Мне нужно каким-то образом по логике поместить data в $content, которая используется в шаблоне для вывода представления. 
Но это не то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил:
Обернул в шаблоне $content в блок div class="app-container"
Теперь ответ аякса выводится туда, и + нужно было делегировать событие по клику на иконку удаление.